# Prove that 9 | $a_k +... +a_1+a_0$ implies that 9 | $a_k 10^k +... + a_1 10^1 + a_o 10^0$

Tags: divisibility

How to prove that :

9 | $a_k+... +a_1+a_0$ implies that

9 | $a_k 10^k +... +a_1 10^1 + a_o 10^0$

where | denotes the divisibility sign (that is, I need to prove that if $a_k+... a_1+a_0$ is divisible by 9 then so is $a_k 10^k +... a_1 10^1 + a_o 10^0$).

Comment: It is actually a co-implication.

Comment: It is sufficient to show the difference is divisible by 9. It is sufficient to show (10^k-1) is divisible by 9. But this is 10^k-1^k, which by the formula for the difference of kth powers is divisible by 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $10 \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$ so $10^n \equiv 1^n \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$. This means $$a_k+ \cdots + a_0 \equiv a_k10^k+ \cdots + a_0 \pmod{9}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Apply the binomial expansion to $10^n=(9+1)^n$.

Comment: I got the answer, but how does the expansion help?

Comment: @Tony The expansion proves that $10^n \equiv 1^n\equiv 1(\mod 9)$.

Answer (score 0):

Expand $(9+1)^j$. In the expansion, every term has a factor $9$ except for $1$.That's where you are to apply your hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

For a number %n% to be divisible by 9 the sum of it's digit must be divisible by 9. So,
$a_k 10^k +… + a_1 10^1 + a_o 10^0$ holds true if, for the k digit number n
$$S = a_k +… + a_1  + a_o$$ is divisible by 9, 
i.e. $9 | a_k+... +a_1+a_0$ which is the provided statement.